# Javascript shows inconsisten value on different PC/Laptop

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2013

I have this simple code bellow written in **Javascript** run in Visual Studio 2013 .Net Framework 4

```
var total = MyURLDecode(data.Data[i].total);
html += '<div class="cell total">' + (total * 1) + '%</div>'
```

The total is **float** Data type, when it reached this formula (**total** * 1), the result is **NaN**, but strangely on my Friend's PC, it shows the proper result (e.g. 4.50, not **NaN**).

So, for the workaround, i add this function **parseFloat**

```
var total = parseFloat(MyURLDecode(data.Data[i].total))
```

and it's worked while my friend doesn't need **parseFloat**;

FYI, I used the **same exact code**, **same exact tools** (Visual Studio Ultimate 2013), **same exact browser** for testing, **same exact .Net Framework**.

I've been googling it since yesterday, but no luck for me.

Anyone can help me or diagnose where is the problem?

Comment: do `consol.log(total.split(''));` to see what are the character in the string.

Comment: will try it, and will get back to you asap

Comment: can you try parsing the number using `parseFloat(number)`

Comment: @JordanHendrix, yup that's exactly my workaround, but i can't understand why i have to use it, while my friends doesnt need it

Comment: just saw your edit, weird,

Comment: @JordanHendrix, i know right, its like a black magic

Comment: @DominiqueFortin the result is 4,50

Comment: "The total is float Data type" --- how do you know that?

Comment: `4,50` <--- it's not a number, it's a string. Numbers cannot have `,` in JS. Which leads us to the "answer": locales?

Comment: @zerkms, well actually the values are various, (100, 200, 4,50, 50, etc), the problem is if it's read as a string, why does my friend can get the proper result ? FYI, i could use parseInt too

Comment: What is the locale on your machine and on your friend's one?

Comment: @zerkms , wait, ill compare it

Comment: @Webster What did `consol.log(total.split(''));` give you?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin , when i debug, it returns the value like 4,50 or 100. but the problem already fixed, thanks

Comment: @zerkms, great job sir! you saved my day, its the Locale setting problem, and the problem already solved! Please post your answer, and ill give you an upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few educated guesses we together have found out that it's locales that to blame.

Personally I would suggest to use nothing but `.` as a decimal mark.

Comment: thanks for the help! for now, ill keep using parseFloat as a workaround, because the decimal mark could be . or ,